# What does a trailing colon mean in the name of a Rake task?

Tags: ruby, rake, symbols

In the custom Rake task example:

```
desc "I am short, but comprehensive description for my cool task"
task task_name: [:prerequisite_task, :another_task_we_depend_on] do
  # All your magic here
  # Any valid Ruby code is allowed
end
```

What does the colon suffix after `task_name` indicate? Normally, the task name is a symbol - what's different about this if you have prerequisites?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [literal `{task_name: [:symbol]}`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Hashes) is a shorthand notation for `{:task_name => [:symbol]}`, this notation was introduced with Ruby 1.9:

```
{task_name: [:symbol]}
# => {:task_name=>[:symbol]}
```

Your example is actually equivalent to:

```
task :task_name => [:prerequisite_task, :another_task_we_depend_on] do
  ...
```

If you have no prerequisites you have to use the usual symbol notaion:

```
task :task_name do
  ...
```

The [Ruby Style Guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide) suggests to prefer the newer, "JSON style", notation.

Comment: The fact that you need to use either `task_name:` or `:task_name` depending on whether the symbol is part of a hash key, makes me prefer the old hashrocket syntax even more. It might not always look quite as pretty, but it's much more consistent and works the same way in more situations.

Comment: @sockmonk So do I, I've mentioned the Ruby Style Guide just for completeness.

Comment: Yikes. My first thought was that this would make it easier to copy json hash definitions directly into ruby, but it doesn't even do that since the hash key can't be a string with the : separator.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax `something: value` means exactly same as `:something => value`. It is just a little more readable.